# Curved lines on extrusion

Tags: 3d-view

I was working on creating straight lines to form a plane and I'm not sure what I've clicked but suddenly, all my lines became curved.

Is there any ways to fix this?
[image]

[image]

Update:

The Subdivision modifier's view is set to 1
[image]

Comment: Going to guess you have a subsurf modifier with a view set to 1. Can be automatically done by hitting Ctrl 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the subsurf modifier is active on fireframe in edit mode, just clic the last button (little triangle) in the modifier view settings.

[image]